# How do I bind data using ng-model with ng-repeat ( within a form )

Tags: angularjs, binding

I have an angular scope variable that is an array of objects and is bound to a form group, when a button is clicked it creates a new form group that the use can fill in. Each form group contains two fields name and number. I'm trying to figure out hoe to bind the form fields in the form to the data in the objects within the array. Just incase that made no sence, I want a form that has a dynamic number of fields that are bound to objects within an array in the scope.

Here is my code

in the controller;

```
    $scope.choices = [{name: 'thename1', number:"10"}];


    // This function adds aditional nutrients
    $scope.addChoice = function() {
        var newItemNo = $scope.choices.length+1;
        $scope.choices.push({'name':'choice'+newItemN, number""});
        console.log(JSON.stringify$scope.choices));
    };
```

in my view i have the following code

```
                    <fieldset data-ng-repeat="choice in choices">
                        <legend>Choice</legend>
                        <!-- START row -->
                        <div class="row" >
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Name</label>
                                    <input type="text" ng-model="choice.name" name="name" placeholder="Test" class="form-control" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Target Volume (ml/l)</label>
                                    <input type="text" ng-model="choice.number" name="target-volume" placeholder="132" class="form-control" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- END row -->
                    </fieldset>
                    <div> Testing
                        <button type="button" class="mb-sm btn btn-pink"  ng-click="addChoice()">Add Another Choice</button>
                    </div>
```

EDIT

ok so It works as expected, but when I try to save the results it fails for instance if I have a create function

```
    $scope.create = function() {
        console.log('this.choices' + JSON.stringify(this.choices));
```

}

the first console log logs the correct object while the one in the create function does not. Am i missing something? I've also tried $scope.choices in the second function as well but it does not work

Comment: Your code has a typo `number""10`.
Other than that, what is your question? What is not working for you?

Comment: Any luck at this one?

Comment: It was a typo but only on stack exchange .... my problem is, even though I bind the form fields to the data, when I update the form field it does not update the data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply push a new variable to the array and it should work. even empty object is enough. see the below implementation

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('formController', function($scope) {
  $scope.choices = [{}];

  $scope.addChoice = function() {
    $scope.choices.push({});

    console.log($scope.choices);
  };

  $scope.submitChoices = function() {
    console.log($scope.choices);
    $scope.submittedChoices = angular.copy($scope.choices);
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="formController">
  <fieldset data-ng-repeat="choice in choices track by $index">
    <legend>Choice</legend>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Name</label>
          <input type="text" ng-model="choice.name" name="name" placeholder="Test" class="form-control" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Target Volume (ml/l)</label>
          <input type="text" ng-model="choice.number" name="target-volume" class="form-control" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
  <div>
    <button type="button" class="mb-sm btn btn-pink" ng-click="addChoice()">Add Another Choice</button>
    <hr/>
    <button type="button" class="mb-sm btn btn-pink" ng-click="submitChoices()">Submit Choices</button>
    <div>
      <pre>{{submittedChoices | json: 2}}</pre>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://plnkr.co/edit/vy8tr5wGbGi3kxnBpsWW?p=preview) is working Plunker.

There where just a couple typos:

```
$scope.choices.push({'name':'choice'+newItemNo, number: 10});
```

while you had:

```
$scope.choices.push({'name':'choice'+newItemN, number""10});
```

`newItemN` was undefined, `number""10` - not valid syntax

Comment: So the function seems to work, and append to the array, but when I attempt to take the value of the form and dod something with it, it appears that the array does not change ( see edits )

Comment: I've made some updates to Plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/vy8tr5wGbGi3kxnBpsWW?p=preview. Take a look if that is what you expect...

Comment: Ok the error was totally my bad, I had a multi - panel form and had ng-controller defined for two parts of the form, I'm assuming that this created two instances of the controller, which is why it appeared like my variable was not changing